# Keep Linux boot messages on screen at first login prompt

Tags: linux, debian

When my Debian stretch/sid boots up, it prints some messages, but then it clears the screen and diplays the login prompt. (Cli-version, I'm not using X)

Is it possible to see these messages (some might be important...) and not clear the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Hit Shift-PageUp and you can scroll back through the boot messages.

Comment: A solution for non-techs would be preferred ;-)

Comment: Your non-techs must be **really** non-tech if they can't handle a simple two-key combination.